# DefaultListModel in Java

Tags: java, swing, list, user-interface, defaultlistmodel

What is `DefaultListModel` in Java? and What is its purpose?
I tried to google it but didn't get any proper explanation for it!

Comment: all data for view (JList) are stored in model (XxxListModel), basically all JComponents have got own model,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DefaultListModel` is a implementation of the `ListModel` that extends from `AbstractListModel`.

Internally, it is backed by `List` implementation.

It's intention is to provide a simple implementation of the `ListModel` that you can use for modelling simple data models where having to extend from the `AbstractListModel` or implement the `ListModel` interface would be overkill for accomplishing the same task

Answer (score 7):

It works as a `Model` (predefined) for `JList`

Swings follows MVC and [DefaultListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) plays its part as `M` in MVC.

There are 3 ways to create model:

- [DefaultListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html)

  Everything is pretty much taken care of by language framework.
- [AbstractListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html)

  You manage the data and invoke the "fire" methods. For this approach, you must subclass `AbstractListModel` and implement the `getSize` and `getElementAt` methods inherited from the `ListModel` interface.
- [ListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html)

  You manage everything.

Comment: Dead links on this answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a link to an example of using ListModel and DefaultListModel, its the second link when you google it.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AnexampleofJListwithaDefaultListModel.htm